# Hard to get the geofencing running on test phone - IOS

Tags: ios

This is my first post every here. Woohoo.

Here is my story ... I spent about a week trying tutorials about geofencing in IOS. The problem is that i have to do it in Objective-C for now.

I am trying to get a small app to run this geofencing but i keep having problems with the actual trigger events.

I am testing it on my actual phone (iPhone 7Plus) and i can't get to make some events show on the screen whether i'm inside the region or out.

i will paste code from the .h and .m files. these are the only ones that i have implemented so far.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *myLat;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *myLon;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *destLat;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *destLon;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *diff;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *answer;
@property BOOL alwaysOn;
@property BOOL isCLickOn;

@property (retain, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

@end
```

... and this what i have in my .m file:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()


@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    //    [self showAlertMessage:@"Test" message:@"Maybe works"];
    //    [self showAlertMessage:@"Test" message:@"Maybe works"];
    [self setupTheAuthorizations];

    if(!_isCLickOn){
        [self startTheRegionMonitoring];
    }

//    _answer.text = @"Merge";
}

- (void) setupTheAuthorizations {
    _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [_locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    _locationManager.delegate = self;
    [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];


    //check the type of authorization
    CLAuthorizationStatus authStatus = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];

    switch (authStatus) {
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways:
            // should do somethinglike getting the things started and stuff like that ...
            _alwaysOn = YES;
            break;
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined:
            [_locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
        default:
            break;
    }

}

- (void) startTheRegionMonitoring {

    if (_alwaysOn && [CLLocationManager isMonitoringAvailableForClass:[CLRegion class]]){
        CLLocationDegrees latitude = 37.972004;
        CLLocationDegrees longitude = -121.293740;
        CLLocationDistance radius = 200;
        CLLocationCoordinate2D center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);

        CLCircularRegion *region = [[CLCircularRegion alloc] initWithCenter:center radius:radius identifier:@"CH"];
        region.notifyOnEntry = YES;
        region.notifyOnExit = YES;
        _destLat.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", latitude];
        _destLon.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", longitude];

        _myLat.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", _locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude];
        _myLon.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", _locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];

        [_locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region];

    }
    _isCLickOn = YES;
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status {

}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
         didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region{
    NSLog(@"entered region");
    if ([region.identifier isEqualToString:@"CH"]){
        _answer.text = @"IN";

        CLLocation *me = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:_locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude
                                                    longitude:_locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];

        CLLocation *dest = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:37.972004
                                                      longitude:-121.293740];
        int dist = [me distanceFromLocation:dest];

        _diff.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", dist];
    }
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
          didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region{
    NSLog(@"entered region");
    if ([region.identifier isEqualToString:@"CH"]) {
        _answer.text = @"OUT";

        CLLocation *me = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:_locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude
                                                    longitude:_locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];

        CLLocation *dest = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:37.972004
                                                      longitude:-121.293740];
        int dist = [me distanceFromLocation:dest];

        _diff.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", dist];


    }
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didStartMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_8,__IPHONE_5_0) __TVOS_PROHIBITED __WATCHOS_PROHIBITED{
    NSLog(@"Monitoring started");
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"error");
}

- (void) showAlertMessage:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message {

    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title message:message preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction *cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }];
    [alert addAction:cancel];

    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

What happens is that i don't get any events showing on my phone even when the app is open. so I have a view controller on the storyboard that is supposed to show my location and destination location and to show the distance between the two objects. But it doesn't show it even if i walk 400 meters and then i walk back to the center.

I know that Swift is what I should use, and I will switch to Swift but for right now I am really wanting to understand the process that goes in this geofencing thing.

Any help will be appreciated. I am also pretty new at programming so I still have things that I am trying to learn and understand about Objective-C in particular.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that. I am still trying getting used to this.